# Import CSV File in phpmyadmin using php

Tags: php, csv

Here is my code to import csv file using php. I can tun derstand the errors.Please get out of it....

```
             <?php

           require_once 'database.php';

                $database=new Database;
              $database->connect();

       if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$file = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,10000, ","))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO personalinfo( id,name, age, gender, occupation, contact, email, uname, paswrd, created_date ) VALUES
        (
            '".addslashes($data[0])."',
            '".addslashes($data[1])."',
            '".addslashes($data[2])."',
            '".addslashes($data[3])."',
            '".addslashes($data[4])."',
            '".addslashes($data[5])."',
            '".addslashes($data[6])."',
            '".addslashes($data[7])."',
            '".addslashes($data[8])."',
            NOW()
        )
    ";
    $database->insert($query);
    echo "INSERT INTO personalinfo( id,name, age, gender, occupation, contact, email, uname, paswrd, created_date ) VALUES
        (
            '".addslashes($data[0])."',
            '".addslashes($data[1])."',
            '".addslashes($data[2])."',
            '".addslashes($data[3])."',
            '".addslashes($data[4])."',
            '".addslashes($data[5])."',
            '".addslashes($data[6])."',
            '".addslashes($data[7])."',
            '".addslashes($data[8])."',
            NOW()
        )";
    echo "<br />";
    echo("Data inserted");
 fclose($file);
}

 } 

 ?>
```

Error comes like this:-

Notice: Undefined index: file1 in /var/www/trainees/B9/Jinal/mvc/import.php on line 10

Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/trainees/B9/Jinal/mvc/import.php on line 11

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/trainees/B9/Jinal/mvc/import.php on line 12

Comment: show your code for importing csv

Comment: try this 
http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql

Comment: i have uploaded the code please go thru it and suggest me my mistakes.Its not working.

Comment: you file is messing and $_FILES["file1"] is empty .So plz show the code from where you upload the .csv file .

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example but you need to adapt to ur need

```
set_time_limit(10000);

$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','password');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db", $con);

$fp = fopen("file.csv", "r");

while( !feof($fp) ) {
  if( !$line = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ';', '"')) {
     continue;
  }

    $importSQL = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('".$line[0]."','".$line[1]."','".$line[2]."')";

    mysql_query($importSQL) or die(mysql_error());  

}

fclose($fp);
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: thanks a lot.but still i have mentioned my import.php file.Please help me with it

Comment: I used the above code.but the below mentioned error occurs. Warning: fopen(\cccserver.com\www\trainees\B9\Jinal\mvccustomer.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/trainees/B9/Jinal/mvc/import.php on line 19
File data successfully imported to database!!